# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Give me HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: iis, .net-core, kestrel

After using deploying my .NET Core 2.1 App to my server, I get the following error when I access the page:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Following Microsoft's always helpful link on the same page (cough cough), I checked the Event View Log and it states:

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/BLAH.COM' with physical root
>   'D:\inetpub\vhosts\BLAH.com\httpdocs\' failed to start process with
>   commandline 'dotnet .\blah.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80070002 : 0.

The message was not only unhelpful, but completely irrelevant. I tried to enable the web app's logging in web.config:

```
<aspNetCore requestTimeout="23:00:00" processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\blah.dll" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" startupTimeLimit="3600" />
```

Oddly, no files were created in the Log directory until I granted permission to my IWPD process. The files it created weren't in the stdout directory as specified, but were in the parent log directory. They also were empty.

I ran the web app from the command line using:

dotnet .\blah.dll

The application appeared to run and I could see some messages on the screen, but I still got the same 502.2 error accessing the site with no additional information in the logs. I followed the troubleshooting steps for ASP.NET Core 2.1 and it mentioned this:

> If the errors occur when making a request to the app, make a request
>   to the host and port where Kestrel listens. Using the default host and
>   post, make a request to http://localhost:5000/. If the app responds
>   normally at the Kestrel endpoint address, the problem is more likely
>   related to the reverse proxy configuration and less likely within the
>   app.

I ran the web app from the command line and tried to access it using http://localhost:5000. I was finally able to access the site, but I still got the same 502.2 error via IIS.

It's obvious IIS and Kestrel are not communicating with each other.  I don't understand why there's two web servers and how to get them to communicate with each other.

Comment: Not sure how it is in Windows, but Kestrel is supposed to be a thin-layer simple server that is supposed to sit behind a more real-world powerful web server (IIS, Nginx, etc.) So you will need to set IIS as a proxy server for Kestrel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem.  The installer for the server's IIS module doesn't restart or warn the user to restart IIS. Restarting IIS loaded the necessary module.  Clearly, this is a bug by any other name.

Comment: 2019 May - Manual iis reset is still required for .NET Core 2.2.5

Comment: Why can't the stupid installer restart it for you or at least put up an "Restart IIS or it won't work." It's amazing Microsoft is still in business.